# python read lines of an entire file, and efficiently storing the ones I want in lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, text, readline

I have a text file which is repeating the following block structure like this:

> EL_TEXT 
>   LAYER 6 
>   DATATYPE 0 
>   XY 2677000: 2316500
>   2677000: 2340500
>   2707000: 2340500
>   2707000: 2316500
>   2677000: 2316500
>   ENDEL 
>   
>   ...

and this blocks are repeating themselves, with different values, along the text file. They always end in `ENDEL`
I would like to read and find all the lines that are for example "LAYER 6" (or "LAYER 6 \n") and store these lines into a list. Also including the XY coordinates of these blocks into a list of XY tuples  `[(2677000, 2316500), ...]`
so that the final list is something like 
`onelayer6polygon = [(2677000, 2316500), (2677000, 2340500), ...]`
`listofpolygonsL6 = [[(2677000, 2316500), (2677000, 2340500), ...], [...], ...]`
How can I do it efficiently in python? i.e. reading only some lines of the file, and only once, advancing the position `lseek` to skip the coordinates that are not the layer I want. 
As far as I understood `for line in file:` will read all the lines until the `EOF`, but I only need to read and store (and later process) the ones with the layer number I specify. Doing it with a while loop and handling the index is also not good for detecting the `EOF`, right?

Comment: When i do something like this on linux i `popen` `grep` or even `fgrep`

Comment: Do you need to provide cross-plattform support? Since this would be doable on Unix-based systems as mentioned by @GáborErdős. If you are working on Windows or if you have to support multiple platforms you might need to write your own file parser.

Comment: I think the general problem is, that your program will have to read each character of the file to determine the linebreaks. If it skips a character it may skip a linebreak. If each block has a specific number of characters you can skip that number with the `seek()` method.

Comment: You can read several lines every time (9 lines) and keep that which you are interested.

Comment: yes, cross-plattform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understood `for line in file:` will read all the lines until the `EOF`, but I only need to read and store (and later process) the ones with the layer number I specify.

Yes and no. Looping over the file will read the file in its entirety line-by-line, until you reach the end of the file. But it will read one line after another, without storing the contents anyway. So it’s up to you to skip lines you are not interested in, and store information you want to keep as you encounter them.

Note that you do have to read the file completely in order to iterate over lines. There is no concept of jumping between lines, you can only seek on a byte (or character) level, so in order to know what a line is you need to check all characters looking for line breaks. So unless you know that every block is always X characters in total, you will have to read the blocks you are not interested in too in order to find the start of the next block.

That being said, you usually solve this sort of task with a state machine: You read the file line by line, and as you read a line, you may choose to change the state of your machine to set it into a different “mode”.

In your case, a mode may be “within the LAYER 6 block”, so that’s what you should start with:

```
inLayer6Block = False
for line in file:
    # strip trailing whitespace, since every line ends with the line break
    line = line.rstrip()

    # if we see the `LAYER 6` line, we start our block
    if line == 'LAYER 6':
        inLayer6Block = True

    # if we see the `ENDEL` line, we are no longer in the block
    elif line == 'ENDEL':
        inLayer6Block = False
```

So all that’s left now is to add logic to handle the case in between, when `inLayer6Block` is true. I’ll leave this up to you for now to expand on the code above. In general, you want to have a list that stores the content within the block, which you append to as long as you are in the `inLayer6Block` state. In order to store every block separately, you would have another block you append that single-block list to when the block ends.

Comment: I see. I was hoping for a way to skip lines without actually having to read them, since this would be more efficient. could this be done with a while loop and readline() only for the lines I care about? would this be less efficient?

Comment: You can't skip lines because you don't know where lines start and end. Think of it like finding the 10th sentence on a page of text: You have to scan for sentence terminators (dots) in order to do that. And just like that a computer program needs to scan for line breaks. And it has to look at every character to do that; no way around it if you don't know how long a line (or a sentence) is. And a while loop with readline does the same as looping over the file. Just skip (=ignore) the lines you don't care about.

Comment: ok. could you answer also the second part? how to obtain the lists I want. because when doing `line.split()` and `line.split(": ")` to get rid of spaces and that ": " I cannot see how to create the lists I want, so that the coordinates appear as the simple tuples I propose. i.e. parsing (and converting to int) the numbers avoiding the first XY text, and the appearances of ": "

Comment: Split the line by the colon, strip whitespace from each part, and convert each part into an integer: `x, y = [int(part.strip()) for part in line.split(':')]`

Comment: this won't work for the line `XY 2677000: 2316500`, and consequently for looping over the next blocks of text. I miss C fscanf; to advance word by word skipping empty spaces and store into the variable of the type you wanted.

Comment: Just look at the line first. If it `startswith('XY')`, then split that off first. It’s basic string manipulation.